# webclient in c# not get correct result html

Tags: c#, html

I used webclient in c# to fetch html result but it is incorrect.

This is my code snippet.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://kat.cr/");
MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
```

And the result is not what is seen on the HTML page.

> ‹      í}ksÛ8²èçÉ¯ÀjÏnì›@âS¢òÚ’_I6vâµ<ÉÌÉM¥ ’8¦H–•=ûáVÝ_zÉíI=lÓ&dFÊNmjÆ’H 
>   4ÝFãÅŸ>ìŸÿzzHÆÉÄ{õè~«‰çÇ/ã$ ŸµZÓé´9Õ›A4j©Ýn·u…eÄq£—
>   /‰X‹3çÕ#ÿ^LxÂÖ¤ü÷Ô½|ÙØü„û   =Ÿ…¼Aìì×ËFÂ¯’BzNì1‹bž¼L“!µ­û õ“™ÇogÇñjuŸMøËÆ¥Ë§a%KÅ§®“Œ_:üÒµ9?ž×w—y4¶™Ç_ªM¥AnæðØŽÜ0q    ^Ÿ³Èæ;Ð/±Æ1ñùTü²Ë rNÎ?’xLcòWñ•G.Ÿ’Ip™}¦±k‹
>
> ## À7ç„$nâñWïzç„’w®}Á öyE€7~ÑÊÞf%=×¿ ÷^6bì¢xÌ9Ðœ@G-õG|ø²Ñj „%®Ý´ƒI‹yí¨ŠcèNS”*Æ¤‘

What should I do so that I can retrieve the actual page?

Comment: Maybe because the server returned text/plain? Who knows. Did you try Fiddler?

Comment: Looks like an [*encoding*](http://www.sitepoint.com/do-you-know-your-character-encodings/) problem.

Comment: @erikkallen : i will try Fiddler, will update result

Comment: @EBrown : yeah i thinks same you, encoding problem but i don't know to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the html code is compressed.. set the AutomaticDecompression  to GZip.
Just try this code and it will work (tested it with youe webpage)

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
```

Since you asked for a "webClient" Solution (see comment):
Because the webClient implementation is without decompression you will have to make your own DecompressedWebClient. Pretty easy if you inherit from the WebClient class:

```
public class AutomaticDecompressionWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("You can not use this WebClient implementation with an address that is not an http uri.");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my post with a custom WebClient

Comment: Glad it works.. don`t forget to mark the post as an answer so others will find that solution as well

Comment: sorry but i new member in stackoverflow.com, how can to mark your post is answer ?. sorry about my noob